# jade, express, and mysql results

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, pug

I am trying to render the results of an SQL query with Jade. It queries a table containing banners, each of them having a type (3 in total) and a unique id.

This is what I have :

express :

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM banner_idx ORDER BY id_type ASC, id_banner ASC", function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
        if (err) {throw err;}
        res.render('banners', {
            title: results[0].title,
            results: results
        });
    });
```

Jade :

```
ul.listBanners
    - each result in results
        li.banner(data-type=result['id_type'])
        - var item = result['id_banner']+': '+result['name_banner']
        span=item
```

This gives me a list of banners in the order I want. Now I'd like to organize it that way (pseudocode) :

```
ul#id_type1
    list of banners with id_type == 1
ul#id_type2
    list of banners with id_type == 2
ul#id_type3
    list of banners with id_type == 3
```

Is that possible to do with Jade? Should I send 3 results sets from Express instead of 1? The problem would then be that any new id_type would need hardcoding... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`lodash.groupBy`](http://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) to group your result set by `id_type`:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

...
connection.query("SELECT * FROM banner_idx ORDER BY id_type ASC, id_banner ASC", function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
  if (err) {throw err;}
  res.render('banners', {
      title   : results[0].title,
      groups  : _.groupBy(results, 'id_type')
  });
});
```

`groupBy` returns an object which looks like this:

```
{
  '1' : [
    { id_type : 1, ... },
    { id_type : 1, ... },
    ...
  ],
  '2' : [
    { id_type : 2, ... },
    { id_type : 2, ... },
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

So the keys in that object are the values of the property that you're grouping on, `id_type` in this case.

Your template would look something like this:

```
each entries, id in groups
  ul(id = 'id_type' + id)
    each entry in entries
      li #{ entry.id_banner + ': ' + entry.name_banner }
```